# How to display hidden files in mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, macos-high-sierra

So I am receiving this error in my terminal:

```
-bash(637,0x7fffa5467340) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071947448320) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
-bash: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071947447824 bytes
```

After doing some research, I believe this may have something to do with my `.bash_profile`.

However I only know how to open hidden files via terminal and since I cannot access it (because of this error), how can I open hidden files via Finder?

Comment: You could open TextEdit.app and write a shell script to open your file in TextEdit.app. The Problem is, that I don't know a way to make this script executable w/o opening the Terminal.

Comment: Another solution: reboot your Mac into the rescue system, open Terminal and edit the file in your home directory. You probably need `sudo` to get the access rights.

Comment: Should mark one of the answers below as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using macOS Sierra or above, just use the shortcut:

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Open your terminal and paste below commands

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true
$ killall Finder
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to documents folder on your mac and try:

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

or

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

In macOS Sierra Apple added a Finder keyboard shortcut that makes it possible to quickly show all the hidden files and folders. You just need to do the following:

1. Open the Finder
2. Go to Folder
3. Hold down Cmd + Shift + . (dot)
4. All the hidden files will become visible
5. Hold down Cmd + Shift + . (dot) a second time to hide the files again

Alternatively, you could do the following:

1. Open the Finder
2. Choose Go from the menu bar
3. Choose Go to Folder (or Shift + Cmd + G)
4. Type hidden file name starting with a '.'

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to find the solution:

When you open your Finder window, if you want to see hidden files (meaning files that start with `.` such as `.bash_profile`, simply use the following:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>

From there, I found that my `.bash_profile` was over 1GB! (There was something that was causing to repeat its own profile setting recursively...)

After fixing that, terminal works fine now.